# Delete salesforce trigger

Tags: apex, delete, developer

I want to delete apex trigger called RollupCertificationEmail.i install the IDE and make Inactive the the XML from the sandbox but when i tried it to deploy it on the production it is giving me this Error.

```
*** Deployment Log ***
Result: FAILED
Date: October 17, 2017 3:37:30 PM EDT

# Deployed From:
   Project name: Salesforce.com
   Username: myewedalsew@nbpts.org.testnbpts
   Endpoint: login.salesforce.com

# Deployed To:
   Username: myewedalsew@nbpts.org
   Endpoint: login.salesforce.com

# Deploy Results:
   File Name:    package.xml
   Full Name:  package.xml
   Action:  UPDATED
   Result:  SUCCESS
   Problem: n/a

   File Name:    triggers/RollupCertificationEmail.trigger
   Full Name:  RollupCertificationEmail
   Action:  NO ACTION
   Result:  SUCCESS
   Problem: n/a

# Test Results:

Run Failures:
  RollupCertificationEmail_TEST.testEligibleDelete System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Candidate_ID__c]: [Candidate_ID__c]
  RollupCertificationEmail_TEST.testEligibleInsert System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Candidate_ID__c]: [Candidate_ID__c]
  RollupCertificationEmail_TEST.testEligibleUpdate System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Candidate_ID__c]: [Candidate_ID__c]
  RollupCertificationEmail_TEST.testNonEligibleDelete System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Candidate_ID__c]: [Candidate_ID__c]
  RollupCertificationEmail_TEST.testNonEligibleInsert System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Candidate_ID__c]: [Candidate_ID__c]
  RollupCertificationEmail_TEST.testNonEligibleUpdate System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Candidate_ID__c]: [Candidate_ID__c]
  TriggeredSends_TEST.campaignMemberSend System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, SendCampaignMember: execution of AfterInsert

caused by: et4ae5.MCBaseException.InvalidParameterException: Whoops! Marketing Cloud Connect does not have access to the selected object. Contact your administrator to enable objects for Marketing Cloud Connect triggered sends.

Class.et4ae5.triggerUtility.automate: line 30, column 1
Trigger.SendCampaignMember: line 2, column 1: []
```

Here is the Code for the  RollupCertificationEmail trigger :-

```
trigger RollupCertificationEmail on Certification__c (after delete, after insert, after update) {
    system.debug('entering RollupCertificationEmail');

    Set<Id> contactIdsFromTrigger = new Set<Id>();
    List<Contact> contactsFromTrigger = new List<Contact>();
    List<Contact> contactsToUpdate = new List<Contact>();

    // Get contact ids from trigger for lookup
    if (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate) {
        for (Certification__c cert : Trigger.new) {
            contactIdsFromTrigger.add(cert.Contact__c);
        }
    }
    if (Trigger.isDelete) {
        for (Certification__c cert : Trigger.old) {
            contactIdsFromTrigger.add(cert.Contact__c);
        }
    }
    system.debug(contactIdsFromTrigger);

    // Perform lookup of contacts and related certifications
    contactsFromTrigger = [select Id, NBRIC_Provided_Email__c, NBCT_Email__c,
                             (select NBCTs_Renewal_Candidates__c
                              from Certifications3__r)
                           from Contact
                           where IsDeleted = false and
                                 Id in :contactIdsFromTrigger
                           ];
    system.debug(contactsFromTrigger);

    // Cycle through contacts, checking each certification for eligible field
    for (Contact con : contactsFromTrigger) {
        con.NBCT_Email__c = null;
        for (Certification__c cert : con.Certifications3__r) {
            if (cert.NBCTs_Renewal_Candidates__c == '2016-2017 Renewal Candidate') {
                con.NBCT_Email__c = con.NBRIC_Provided_Email__c;
            }
        }
        contactsToUpdate.add(con);
    }

    // Update necessary contacts
    Database.SaveResult[] sResult = Database.update(contactsToUpdate);
    for (Database.SaveResult s : sResult) {
        if (s.isSuccess() == false) {
            for (Database.Error e : s.getErrors()) {
                system.debug('error updating ' + s.getId() + ': ' + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    system.debug('exiting RollupCertificationEmail');
}
```

Comment: You're going to need to fix your unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

If you deactivate an Apex trigger, you also need to comment out any unit test code that references it.  It looks like the test class is RollupCertificationEmail_TEST, so you'll need to edit that class and deploy it together with your deactivated trigger.

Comment: That's interesting. How could a test class **reference a trigger** explicitly?

Comment: A unit test is supposed to exercise the trigger or method it is written for, so if the trigger is disabled then the unit test will fail and prevent deployment.